# Best practice for vertically stacking elements CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like to stack my header ('Sail away today with Starboard Rentals.') and my link buttons on top of each other. I want the nav buttons to be below the h1 on the lower half of the 'home-jumbo' div. What is the best practice to separate these two and position the nav buttons below.

I tried to position the jumbo-btns on their own but my css is not working.

[Site Header Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDaEJ.jpg)

```
return (
        <div className="home-div">
            <div className="home-jumbo">
                <h1 className="jumbo-header">
                    Sail away today with StarboardRentals.
                </h1>
                <div className="jumbo-btns">
                    <Link to="/rent" className="jumbo-btn">
                        Rent
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/about" className="jumbo-btn">
                        About us 
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-deck">
                <div className="boat-cards">
                    <BoatCard addToCart={addToCart} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

```
.home-jumbo {
    width: 80%;
    height: 75%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px;
    border-radius: 1%;
    background-image: url("/public/img/home-bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.home-div {
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}


.jumbo-btns {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css looks pretty good; just add `flex-direction: column;` to `.home-jumbo`

It also looks like you don't need the `jumbo-btns` container, but that's up to you.

Comment: The `.jumbo-btns` container is necessary in case the links are going to be in one row. Without it the buttons would be stacked in one column.

Comment: flex-direction does work, I was just blanking!